# Real cron killed my cron system. Only define( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true ); works

Tags: wp-cron, cron

my host recommended me to disable wp cron for a real cron due to excessive executions.

the cron system broken immediately and scheduled tasks were not happening.

deleting real cron and turning on wp cron did not work.

through random luck, i tried define( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true ); and it worked.

having said so, i really want to revert back to the prior situation where normal wp cron works.  it also messes up when all my links start to have &doing_wp_cron=

i have spent many hours and am desperate! appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: Sorry to hear, but I'm not sure this fits into the scope of this site as it is a very localized question. My suggestion: find out (together with your host maybe) why using real crons did not work - we do it like that in all of our projects and it always worked.

Comment: they tried to brush me off  -.-    am hoping if someone can shed more light.. its weird why alternate wp cron works but usual wp cron no longer works. . .